# Flask Python submit button

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am trying to create a page to register users but the submit button in my bootstrap form isn't working. When I hit the submit button, I get a bad request error. Here is the code in my python file:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['username']:
            error = 'You have to enter a username'
        elif not request.form['email'] or '@' not in request.form['email']:
            error = 'You have to enter a valid email address'
        elif not request.form['password']:
            error = 'You have to enter a password'
        elif get_user_id(request.form['username']) is not None:
            error = 'The username is already taken'
        else:
            print(request.form['username'])
            db = get_db()
            db.execute('INSERT INTO user (username, email, pw_hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                       [request.form['username'], request.form['email'],
                        generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])])
            db.commit()
            flash('You were successfully registered and can login now')
            return render_template('control.html')
    return render_template('register.html')
```

also i have a html file register.html:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %}Sign-up{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-register" role="form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('register') }}">
        <h2 class="form-register-heading">Please sign up</h2>
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" value="{{ request.form.username }}" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" value="{{ request.form.email }}" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required >
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>

</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

I can't find where I did it wrong, I'm new to python and flask!

Comment: `@app.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

try this, POST request should end with '/'

Comment: I tried this but still not working, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `input` fields have no `name` attribute. This will cause all of your checks to result in `KeyError`s. The first step is to add the attribute to each input.

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" value="{{ request.form.username }}" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
```

Note that I also checked the `type` attribute as there is no `username` type. `email` and `password` are valid values, `email` being added in HTML5.

The next step will be to change how you check for the fields. If you only care about the presence of the field, `in` is the way to go.

```
if 'username' not in request.form:
```

If, however, you also want a truty value, the `get` method is what you want.

```
if not request.form.get('username'):
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, first step of your answer fixed my problem completely!